# Convert Java's PBEWithMD5AndDES without salt to JavaScript with crypto

Tags: javascript, java, encryption

I have the following code for decryption in java, I want that to be implemented in nodejs but the i found many tuto for my problem but they use a salt and that don't work when i try to remove the salt system.

My olds functions from java

```
    public void readLastLogin(File lastLogin) {
        try {
            final Cipher ciph = this.openCipher(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE);
            final DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(new CipherInputStream(new FileInputStream(lastLogin), ciph));

            String user = dis.readUTF();
            String token = dis.readUTF();
            dis.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void saveLastLogin(File lastLogin, String user, String token) {
        try {
            final Cipher ciph = this.openCipher(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE);
            final DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(new CipherOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(lastLogin), ciph));

            dos.writeUTF(user);
            dos.writeUTF(token);
            dos.close();
        } catch (final Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private Cipher openCipher(final int mode) throws Exception {
        final Random rnd = new Random(43287234L);
        final byte[] data = new byte[8];

        rnd.nextBytes(data);
        final PBEParameterSpec spec = new PBEParameterSpec(data, 5);
        final SecretKey key = SecretKeyFactory
                .getInstance("PBEWithMD5AndDES")
                .generateSecret(new PBEKeySpec("mysecretpassword".toCharArray()));

        final Cipher ret = Cipher.getInstance("PBEWithMD5AndDES");
        ret.init(mode, key, spec);
        return ret;
    }
```

I try this but not working

```
KDF(password, iterations) {
 var key = new Buffer(password,'utf-8');
 var i;
 for (i = 0; i < iterations; i+=1) {
  key = crypto.createHash("md5").update(key).digest();
 }
 return key;
}

getKeyIV(password, iterations) {
 var key = this.KDF(password, iterations);
 var keybuf = new Buffer(key,'binary').slice(0,8);
 var ivbuf = new Buffer(key,'binary').slice(8,16);
 return [ keybuf, ivbuf ];
}

decrypt(message) {
 var kiv = this.getKeyIV('password' ,5);
 var decipher = crypto.createDecipheriv('des-ede', kiv[0], kiv[1]);
 var result = decipher.update(message, 'hex', 'utf-8');
 return result + decipher.final('utf-8');
}
```

**Edit:** The salt generated at runtime of the Java code is hex encoded: `0x0C9D4AE41E8315FC`

```java
final byte[] data = new byte[8];
data[0] = 12;
data[1] = -99;
data[2] = 74;
data[3] = -28;
data[4] = 30;
data[5] = -125;
data[6] = 21;
data[7] = -4;
```

Comment: `PBEWithMD5AndDES` in the Java code uses an 8 bytes salt by definition. Without salt the Java code throws an *InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: Salt must be 8 bytes long*.  So the question is, what key derivation are you using on the encryption side. Post the encryption code (especially regarding the key derivation). By the way, `des-ede` denotes Triple DES (2TDEA).

Comment: @Topaco My encryption code don't need salt, i already post it (first code).
I use wrong encryption with des-ede ?

Comment: In the first code, the salt is called `data` (for whatever reason), i.e. the first code uses a salt as well.

Comment: I don't salt the password and all tutorial salt password too, and my salt is random and i don't need it for decode with my java code @Topaco

Comment: *...I don't salt the password...* and *...my salt is random...* contradict each other. It is not clear from your question what the problem is. Post the code you use for the **en**cryption. If it is the encryption counterpart of the Java code that applies PBEWithMD5AndDES, it is mandatory that you use a salt. If you use a random salt (which is the correct approach!), the salt has to be sent together with the ciphertext to the decrypting side (usually concatenated). Note that the salt is not secret (but must be randomly generated for each encryption).

Comment: I updated my code, i don't save the salt and i can decode the file with a random salt, and when i try to decode the same file with js that doesn't work @Topaco

Comment: Since `Random()` is called with the same seed, the same salt is generated each time, i.e. the Java code uses a *static* salt (which is insecure btw). You will probably not find a NodeJS implementation that is analogous to `Random()`, so you will need to determine the salt at runtime of the Java code (logging or debugging). This salt is then to be used in the NodeJS code.

Comment: Oh i understand ! I updated the code without Random, I will try to integrate with nodejs @Topaco

Comment: Your last change resulted in missing the `saveLastLogin()` method and the use of the `Random()` class, both of which are relevant to the answer. I have therefore rolled back your change and appended the code you posted regarding the salt to the end of the original question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are three issues in the code:

- The Java code uses [`writeUTF()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/io/DataOutputStream.html#writeUTF(java.lang.String)). This is based on [modified UTF-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#Modified_UTF-8), with two additional bytes prepended to contain the data size. A NodeJS library for modified UTF-8 is [*mutf-8*](https://github.com/sciencesakura/mutf-8).
- Instead of `des-ede` ([3DES/2TDEA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triple_DES#Keying_options) in ECB mode), `des-cbc` (DES in CBC mode) must be applied. If DES is not available in the used NodeJS version, it can be mimicked with 3DES/2TDEA in CBC mode, `des-ede-cbc`, where the 8 bytes key has to be concatenated with itself to a 16 bytes key, reducing 3DES to DES. This workaround has the disadvantage of a performance loss.
- The Java code applies a static 8 byte salt because `Random()` is instantiated with a static seed. This salt can be determined at runtime to (hex encoded): `0x0C9D4AE41E8315FC`.

[*pbewithmd5anddes-js*](https://gist.github.com/qzaidi/5401800#file-pbewithmd5anddes-js) is a port of `PBEWithMD5AndDES` to NodeJS, from which the `KDF()`, `getKeyIV()` and `decrypt()` methods can be used, but must be adapted taking into account the above points. In addition, the functionality of `readUTF()` (the counterpart of `writeUTF()`) must be implemented. One possible solution is:

```js
var crypto = require('crypto');
const { MUtf8Decoder } = require("mutf-8");

var pbewithmd5anddes = {

  KDF: function(password,salt,iterations) {
    var pwd = Buffer.from(password,'utf-8');
    var key = Buffer.concat([pwd, salt]);
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < iterations; i+=1) {
      key = crypto.createHash('md5').update(key).digest();
    }
    return key;
  },

  getKeyIV: function(password,salt,iterations) {
    var key = this.KDF(password,salt,iterations);
    var keybuf = Buffer.from(key,'binary').subarray(0,8);
    var ivbuf = Buffer.from(key,'binary').subarray(8,16);
    return [ keybuf, ivbuf ];
  },

  decrypt: function(payload,password,salt,iterations) {
    var encryptedBuffer = Buffer.from(payload,'base64');
    var kiv = this.getKeyIV(password,salt,iterations);
    //var decipher = crypto.createDecipheriv('des-cbc', kiv[0], kiv[1]);                              // Fix 1: If supported, apply DES-CBC with key K
    var decipher = crypto.createDecipheriv('des-ede-cbc', Buffer.concat([kiv[0], kiv[0]]), kiv[1]);   // otherwise DES-EDE-CBC with key K|K  
    var decryptedBuf = Buffer.concat([decipher.update(encryptedBuffer), decipher.final()])
    var decrypted = this.readUTF(decryptedBuf)                                                        // Fix 2: apply writeUTF counterpart
    return decrypted;
  },

  readUTF: function(decryptedBuf) {
    var decoder = new MUtf8Decoder()
    var decryptedData = []
    var i = 0;
    while (i < decryptedBuf.length){
      var lengthObj = decryptedBuf.readInt16BE(i);
      var bytesObj = decryptedBuf.subarray(i+2, i+2+lengthObj);
      var strObj = decoder.decode(bytesObj)
      decryptedData.push(strObj)
      i += 2 + lengthObj;
    }
    return decryptedData;
  }
};
```

---

Test:

On the Java side, the following is executed:

```java
saveLastLogin(file, "This is the first plaintext with special characters like §, $ and €.", "This is the second plaintext with special characters like §, $ and €.");
```

The raw ciphertext written to `file` is Base64 encoded:

```
Ow8bdeNM0QpNFQaoDe7dhG3k9nWz/UZ6v3+wQVgrD5QvWR/4+sA+YvqtnQBsy35nQkwhwGRBv1h1eOa587NaFtnJUWVHsRsncLWZ05+dD2rYVpcZRA8s6P2iANK6yLr+GO/+UpZpSe0fA4fFqEK1nm3U7NXdyddfuOlZ3h/RiyxK5819LieUne4F8/TpMzT0RIWkxqagbVw=
```

This can be decrypted on the NodeJS side with:

```js
var payload = 'Ow8bdeNM0QpNFQaoDe7dhG3k9nWz/UZ6v3+wQVgrD5QvWR/4+sA+YvqtnQBsy35nQkwhwGRBv1h1eOa587NaFtnJUWVHsRsncLWZ05+dD2rYVpcZRA8s6P2iANK6yLr+GO/+UpZpSe0fA4fFqEK1nm3U7NXdyddfuOlZ3h/RiyxK5819LieUne4F8/TpMzT0RIWkxqagbVw=';
var password = 'mysecretpassword';
var salt = Buffer.from('0C9D4AE41E8315FC', 'hex');
var iterations = 5;
var decrypted = pbewithmd5anddes.decrypt(payload,password,salt,iterations);
console.log(decrypted);
```

with the output:

```
[
  'This is the first plaintext with special characters like §, $ and €.',
  'This is the second plaintext with special characters like §, $ and €.'
]
```

---

Note that the code contains serious vulnerabilities:

- `PBEWithMD5AndDES` uses a key derivation based on the broken MD5 digest (PBKDF1), and as encryption algorithm the deprecated DES (officially withdrawn almost 20 years ago).
- Use of a static salt.
- An iteration count of 5 is generally much too small.
- `Random()` (unlike `SecureRandom()`) is not cryptographically strong. Also note that it is not a good idea to use a PRNG like `Random()` for deterministic key derivation, as the implementation may change, leading to different results even with the same seed.